# No wireless interface after initial setup Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, boot

The wifi worked before the initial setup, but after reboot it stopped working.

raspi-config says no wireless interface found when trying to set up the wifi.

wpa_supplicant.conf states:

```
country=US  
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev  
update_config=1  

network={  
        ssid="myssid"  
        scan_ssid=1  
        psk="mypwd"  
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
}
```

Checked the file /etc/network/interfaces and it states:

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d (this directory is empty when checking)
mapping wlan0
script /root/bin/map_iface (this directory is empty when checking)
source /boot/realtimepi-network.txt (this file does not exist)

It seems the wifi (wlan0) is not properly initialized at boot.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `scan_ssid=1` infers you have a hidden SSID - more trouble than they are worth esp with Pi boxes - change WLAN config to show SSID - no security benefit - sniffer can find them as devices transmit ssid in plain text on connection!  The lines 'ssid' to 'key_mgmt' should be indented.  If you used Notepad or File Editor etc then the file has CRLF at the end of each line.  Delete the file and recreate with `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` . Key_mgmt line I find redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have installed Raspberry Pi Os Buster. If it's not buster, first download it from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ and try again.

Buster uses `dhcpcd` to enable detected WiFi interfaces. In particular, when a WiFi interface is found, `dhcpcd` will launch:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

This is what enables `raspi-config` to edit the `wpa_supplicant` configuration.

However, if **anything extra** is added to `/etc/network/interfaces`, then `dhcpcd` will see it and it won't activate anything. You've reported these extra lines:

```
mapping wlan0
script /root/bin/map_iface (this directory is empty when checking)
source /boot/realtimepi-network.txt (this file does not exist)
```

This is enough to stop `dhcpcd` working. It also means you've done something to your configuration which you haven't told us about.

`realtimepi-network.txt` is used by https://github.com/guysoft/RealtimePi/ and so your question may be more appropriate as an issue there. This existing issue might help you find the solution to your problem:

https://github.com/guysoft/RealtimePi/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with OpenMediaVault 5. It messes up the Wi-Fi after install... So far no fix as of 1/1/2021

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo dhcpcd` command helped - network settings were refreshed and connection established automatically after the command completes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating or editing `wpa_supplicant.conf` I tried to solve the problem using the following script in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
      wlan0:
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
        access-points:
          "SSID":
            password: "<YOUR PASSWORD>"
```

> And make sure to submit the changes :
>
> `sudo netplan generate`
>
> `sudo netplan apply`

Now check if it is (wlan0) configured correctly and works fine `networkctl`:
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135658)